# How to get a custom variable into a phtml file?

Tags: php, magento2

I have created a custom variable from Magento 2 admin (System > Custom Variables). My custom variable code is "test_var".

How can I get that value in a phtml file?

Answer (score 10):

for this you have to use object Manager and load model using its variable Code

After that you can get its plain value, html value and its name too.

```
 <?php 
$model = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->loadByCode('test_var');
$plain_value = $model->getPlainValue();
$html_value = $model->getHtmlValue();
$name = $model->getName();
?>
```

Comment: Using object manager like this is generally frowned upon.  You should probably write this in the block logic and do a dependency injection with a getter.  Here's a write up on how to do that.  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#injection-types-used-in-magento

Comment: To add on to espradley''s comment, you refer here for more info: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly

Answer (score 10):

The "clean" way is to do this with dependency injection.

Create your own block:

```
namespace MyCompany\MyBlockName\Block;

class MyBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_varFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Variable\Model\VariableFactory $varFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        $this->_varFactory = $varFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getVariableValue() {
        $var = $this->_varFactory->create();
        $var->loadByCode('test_var');
        return $var->getValue('text');
    }

}
```

And use it in your `.phtml` file:

```
<?php echo $this->getVariableValue() ?>
```

Comment: Adding to Arnaud's answer, use `$var->validate() === TRUE` to check for code.

Answer (score 3):

Please use this code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $variable = $objectManager->create('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable');

    $value = $variable->loadByCode('variableCode')->getPlainValue();
    echo $value;
```

Comment: Using object manager directly is against Magento coding standards as mentioned in other comments: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html#usage-rules

Answer (score 2):

To get custom variables **taking into account the different store views** it's possible to use the Object Manager:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeID = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();

// HTML VALUE
$objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->setStoreId($storeID)->loadByCode('your_custom_variable')->getHtmlValue();

// PLAIN VALUE
$objectManager->get('Magento\Variable\Model\Variable')->setStoreId($storeID)->loadByCode('your_custom_variable')->getPlainValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in magento 2.2 in a phtml file :

```
$manager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$value = $manager
         ->get('Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig')
         ->get('shop/url') // other ex: 'db/connection/default/host'
;
```

Comment: Using object manager directly is against Magento coding standards as mentioned in other comments: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html#usage-rules

Answer (score -1):

```
// To get the TEXT value of the custom variable:
Mage::getModel('core/variable')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->loadByCode('custom_variable_code')->getValue('text');

// To get the HTML value of the custom variable:
Mage::getModel('core/variable')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->loadByCode('custom_variable_code')->getValue('html');
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried it and got the following error.

Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage' not found in ...

Comment: I think you are doing in external file. please add following code in top of the file.
`require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();`

Comment: This response is for Magento1, not Magento2 as requested.